# back button on iPhone app

Tags: iphone

i want to make a back button in my Iphone app which is similar to this :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEAkVCouI_Y  (its name is "retour" in french).
unfortunately i can`t find it in the library in interface builder..any suggestions ?? THX in advance :)

Comment: Are you talking about the ripple effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

The button labeled "retour" is a standard back button from a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  In the video, the main interface is a UINavigationController. A UITableViewController is visible, and transitions to another view controller via `pushViewController:animated:`.

View Controllers, including Navigation Controllers are described in the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html).

Answer (score 0):

A [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a class that automatically handles the going back operations. It is basically a stack of view controllers (stored as an NSArray)—you push and pop (add and remove) views from the stack (as in a stack of cards—only one is visible on top). When you're on any view other than the bottom-most (the root view [controller]), the back button will automatically appear with the title of the previous view. Check out [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Comment: THX all, you really save me :))